# How to index from an array in increments with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an array with multiple data, and I'd like to index a div with an incremental value.

```
var fancyboxInfo = [
'Title1', 'Details1', 'Location1', 
'Title2', 'Details2', 'Location2',
'Title3', 'Details3', 'Location3',
]

$(".fancybox").each(function(index) {
   $(this).attr("title", fancyboxInfo[index]);
});
```

Using 'each', the following ends up being:

```
<div class="fancybox" title="Title1"></div>
<div class="fancybox" title="Details1"></div>
<div class="fancybox" title="Location1"></div>
```

I want to make it index [0], [3], [6] etc. Can this be done using jQuery index?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fNNkx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 0;
$(".fancybox").each(function() {
   if (x < $(".fancybox").length) {
      $(this).attr("title", fancyboxInfo[x]);
      x += 3;
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this Norse. It's the most adaptable one for my needs. Really appreciate it, will accept it as the answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".fancybox").each(function(index) {
   if(index % 3 == 0) {
      $(this).attr("title", fancyboxInfo[index]);
   }
});
```

Comment: This will not give the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
$(".fancybox").each(function(index) {
   $(this).attr("title", fancyboxInfo[(index*3)]);
});
```

Comment: fancy box has 3 elements. The array has 9 elements. The mapping is 0-0, 1-3, 2-6. The index will be 0,1,2. So its index*3 and not index+=3.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
var fancyboxInfo = [
    'Title1', 'Details1', 'Location1',
    'Title2', 'Details2', 'Location2',
    'Title3', 'Details3', 'Location3',
    'Title4', 'Details3', 'Location3',        
  ]
i=0;
$(".fancybox").each(function(index) {


      $(this).attr("title", fancyboxInfo[i]);
  i = i+3;
});
```

Comment: I've marked this up, as this also works perfectly (but came after I'd already accepted the answer). Thanks! :)